# TextView frame visible but not tappable after animating Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, textview, core-animation

Note: I am using 1 pod ([iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel))

Note II: project files https://ufile.io/vgopt <- I was having issues with GitHub so I had to store the project files in uploadfiles.io

I have compact cards that show basic data. After tapping "START" the cards expand and reveal more data:
[image: compact card / expanded card]

To achieve this animation I create all my constraints beforehand programmatically(inside sculptureCard.swift). I assign different priority values to each one of my constraints and then inside my ViewController's "changeLayout" method I swap priorities from 998 to 1 and vice-versa.

**The issue** is that this new data is very long and I need to be able to scroll down to see it all. Initially, I was using(and I hope to use) a scrollView. I decided to use a textView instead to make this as simple as possible. However, only **HALF** my textView responds to my gestures. 
[image]

I think my textView is working ONLY within the area that was initially constrained against; the compact card view(textView is also initially height 0). But I need to have this textView recognize gestures all over its surface, not just half. 
A similar conundrum occurs with my buttons. After the animation occurs, only half the button is tappable anymore. I believe the same issue that affects my textView is affecting my buttons. Perhaps the way I animate my views is incorrect. 
[image]

Furthermore, but still related is the issue of having to increase the size of the cards by also adjusting their "y" position to -125. I believe this not the right way to modify view frames. x:0 y:0 should move my card to the top of its carousel containing view, but it doesn't. Therefore I have to use -125.
[image]

All animation occurs inside the ViewController's method "changeLayout"(very long so no picture). And all the constraints are created in my custom class "sculptureCard".

I animate my views after the carousel container constraints have been changed, I've chained my animations with completion blocks. I call "view.layoutIfNeeded()" all the necessary times(I think) in order to make this work. I've tried calling that method all over the place and under different circumstances. I've tried other methods such as "layoutMargins" and "layoutSubViews" and almost everything else I could think would maybe work.

I think I know what the issue is (the frame not being updated on my views, even when the views display properly) but I can't find a solution to this problem.